# Setting variables that depend on other variables in TCSH

Tags: unix, set, environment-variables, tcsh

I am trying to find a way to use my previously defined variables in a shell script, when defining a new variable. For example, if I had:

```
set num = 20
set min = 1
set max = 10
```

I am looking for a way to create

```
set step = ($max - $min)/$num
```

Where at the moment, using the above results in the error:

"set: Variable name must begin with a letter."

I have found that I can use the expr command to do the calculation. E.g

```
expr {($max - $min)/$num}
```

Will yield the correct result, but I have been unable to find a way to get this into a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

you want the @ command

```
@ step = ($max - $min) / $num
```